# How to avoid the email being trimmed after .\n\n

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta

I have been searching a bug for weeks now - and finally could locate it. However, I need some help how to solve it. The context is an email address confirmation.

Depending on the char-count of the login name, the PHP command quoted_printable_encode() breaks the line before or after a dot which is followed by a newline.

This works ...

```
Ihre E-Mail-Adresse burninleo@abc.net wurde als Kontaktadresse f=C3=BCr das=
 Benutzerkonto "abcdefg.abcdef" auf https://www.snipsnapme.com eingetragen.

Falls Sie dieses Benutzerkonto selbst eingerichtet haben, best=C3=A4tigen S=
ie Ihre korrekte E-Mail-Adresse bitte, indem Sie auf folgenden Link klicken=
```

... while this is trimmed before the dot.

```
Ihre E-Mail-Adresse burninleo@abc.net wurde als Kontaktadresse f=C3=BCr das=
 Benutzerkonto "abcdefg.abcdefg" auf https://www.snipsnapme.com eingetragen=
.

Falls Sie dieses Benutzerkonto selbst eingerichtet haben, best=C3=A4tigen S=
ie Ihre korrekte E-Mail-Adresse bitte, indem Sie auf folgenden Link klicken=
```

As far as I remember \n+dot+\n+\n is a marker for "end of message" - so it is absolutely clear, why the message is trimmed here. However, it does not seem sensible to replace any =\ndot\n\n by something else because quoted_printable_encode() does misunderstand that.

Is there something I have missed? What?

Thanks for your hints!
BurninLeo

---

This is the complete message content as sent to PHP's mail(). As postfix on linux replaces \n by \r\n, the newline character is \n.

```
--=_SubliminalMessagesInCinemaDontWork
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Guten Tag,

Ihre E-Mail-Adresse burninleo@abc.net wurde als Kontaktadresse f=C3=BCr das=
 Benutzerkonto "abcdefg.abcdefg" auf https://www.snipsnapme.com eingetragen=
.

Falls Sie dieses Benutzerkonto selbst eingerichtet haben, best=C3=A4tigen S=
ie Ihre korrekte E-Mail-Adresse bitte, indem Sie auf folgenden Link klicken=
: https://www.snipsnapme.com/admin/act.php?t=3D1234567890ABCDEF

Der Best=C3=A4tigungscode f=C3=BCr Ihre E-Mail-Adresse lautet: 1234567890AB=
CDEF


Falls Sie das Benutzerkonto nicht selbst eingerichtet haben, will m=C3=B6gl=
icherweise eine andere Person Ihre E-Mail-Adresse missbrauchen. In diesem F=
all l=C3=B6schen Sie diese E-Mail bitte einfach.

----------------------------------------------------------
snipsnapme.com - https://www.snipsnapme.com
----------------------------------------------------------
--=_SubliminalMessagesInCinemaDontWork
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head>
<title>Best=C3=A4tigung der E-Mail-Adresse</title>
<style>
body { font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif }
a.button:link { background-color: #00AA00 }
a.button:visited { background-color: #009900 }
a.button:focus,
a.button:hover,
a.button:active { background-color: #66AA00 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Guten Tag,</p>
<p>Ihre E-Mail-Adresse <strong>burninleo@abc.net</strong> wurde als Kontakt=
adresse f=C3=BCr
das Benutzerkonto "abcdefg.abcdefg" auf <strong>https://www.snipsnapme.com<=
/strong> eingetragen.</p>
<p>Falls Sie dieses Benutzerkonto selbst eingerichtet haben, best=C3=A4tige=
n Sie
Ihre korrekte E-Mail-Adresse bitte, indem Sie auf folgenden Knopf klicken.<=
/p>
<p style=3D"padding: 20px 0px">
<a href=3D"https://www.snipsnapme.com/admin/act.php?t=3D1234567890ABCDEF" c=
lass=3D"button" style=3D"padding: 10px 20px; margin: 1px; border: 1px solid=
 white; outline: 1px solid #00AA00; background-color: #00AA00; color: #FFFF=
FF; text-decoration: none">E-Mail-Adresse best=C3=A4tigen</a>
</p>
<p>Der Best=C3=A4tigungscode f=C3=BCr Ihre E-Mail-Adresse lautet: 123456789=
ABCDEF</p>
<p>Falls Sie das Benutzerkonto <u>nicht</u> selbst eingerichtet haben,
will m=C3=B6glicherweise eine andere Person Ihre E-Mail-Adresse missbrauche=
n.
In diesem Fall l=C3=B6schen Sie diese E-Mail bitte einfach.</p>
<div style=3D"margin-top: 24px; border-top: 2px solid #999999; border-botto=
m: 2px solid #999999; padding: 8px 0px">
snipsnapme.com &ndash; <a href=3D"https://www.snipsnapme.com">https://www.s=
nipsnapme.com</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
--=_SubliminalMessagesInCinemaDontWork--
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary for the application to worry about this, it should be handled automatically by the mail software.

Comment: Well - I would greatly appreciate if the mail software did so. But PHP's mail() + Linux postfix hold some special pitfalls for programmers. You cannot, for example, use the RFC's \r\n as newline character using this software combination, but must use \n. And this dot-in-a-single-line issue had cost me hours and hours...

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this on our Linux server running Postfix, and couldn't.

Comment: My test case: `mail('account@domain', 'Testing', "This is a test.\n.\n\nThis is more text.");` I see both lines in the received email.

Comment: Could it be that this problem only occurs in multipart mails (see sample code above)? I (still) observe this problem with PHP 5.3.3-7+squeez and postfix 2.7.1-1+squeeze1. If other versions take care about the dot-problem, then using the workaround below will really become fun :)

Comment: Using your one-line test code I could confirm the problem on my system. Using different systems receiving the email (GMX, GoogleMail) the only line in the email was `This is a test.`

Comment: We're running PHP 5.4.3-6. I'm not sure how to tell what version of Postfix we're running.

Comment: On Debian/Ubuntu: `dpkg -l postfix` - I would not eliminiate the possibility that PHP 5.4 fixes the issue (which raises the question why my Debian has not yet updated to 5.4 ... but this really does not belong here)...

Comment: We're also running postfix 2.7.1-1+squeeze1. I suspect it's a configuration issue on your server. You could try posting on serverfault.com for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prepend a `.` (dot) to all lines containning only dots.

```
preg_replace('/^(\.+)$/m', '.\1', $mail)
```

This is a dirty artifact of your transport layer. SMTP is the most probable culprit (see the call for caution in the [mail function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)) but there may be other low level mecanisms that behave similarly. For example if you tweaked the [sendmail_path](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path) setting or use a buggy `sendmail` program you may experience similar woes.

Comment: Perfectly simple solutions :) Thenka you very much! For those who want to copy & paste, here's the correct PHP command:

`$content = preg_replace('/^(\\.+)$/m', '.\\1', $content);`

Is there any reason why quoted_printable_encode() does not do this on itself???

Comment: It's part of the SMTP protocol, not email encoding.

Comment: @BurninLeo As Barmar notes this trick is not part of MIME email encoding. It is a dirty artifact of your mail transport layer.

Comment: @kmkaplan could you specify "transport layer" more in detail? You are talking about SMTP, right? I am still not perfectly sure which roles PHP, postfix and possibly other software components play in the email sending process - but I definitely prefer a solid solution instead of a single-platform hack...

Comment: @BurninLeo I edited my answer to give more detail about this.

Comment: Doesn't this breaks RFC2045 "a line shall not exceed 75 characters" when a line already count 75 characters?